# how to make DISTINCT, ORDER BY, CASE work together?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, pg

Required sort by condition - if field is exclusive, then sort by `"fees"."exclusive_price"` else by `"fees"."additional_price"`.
SQL completely looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "numbers".* 
FROM "numbers" 
INNER JOIN "users_numbers" ON "users_numbers"."number_id" = "numbers"."id" 
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "users_numbers"."user_id" 
INNER JOIN "fees" ON "fees"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
WHERE "numbers"."state" != 'removed' 
ORDER BY CASE "numbers"."is_exclusive" WHEN TRUE THEN "fees"."exclusive_price" ELSE "fees"."additional_price" END desc"
```

But I get an error (in rails):

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Error because of **distinct**. Without distinct - success.
How to correct SQL?

Added columns from related tables to SELECT - didn't help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "fees"."exclusive_price", "fees"."additional_price", "sender_numbers".*
FROM ...
```

Comment: Since there are multiple rows for each "number" after the joins, how do you decide which row from "fees" to pick. You plain `DISTINCT` currently results in an arbitrary pick, which can change from one invocation to the next.

Comment: I added columns from related table "fees" to SELECT - didn't help.

Comment: The error you report did not come from that query.  It means the connection was already in an invalid state before the query was run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plain `DISTINCT` de-duplicates based on the complete `SELECT` list. The (final) `ORDER BY` step then only accepts expressions that are part of that `SELECT` list.

To order by that `CASE` expression, you'd have to include it in the `SELECT` list. Like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT n.*, CASE WHEN n.is_exclusive THEN f.exclusive_price ELSE f.additional_price END AS order_col
FROM   numbers n
JOIN   users_numbers un ON un.number_id = n.id 
JOIN   users         u  ON u.id = un.user_id 
JOIN   fees          f  ON f.user_id = u.id 
WHERE  n.state <> 'removed' 
ORDER  BY order_col DESC;
```

You would have to wrap that in an outer query to remove `order_col` from the `SELECT` list. But I am not sure, we have the complete picture, yet. And there may be simpler ways ...